# How do I create an rspec test that validates a JSON response?

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails-3, testing, rspec, cancan

I have a Groups Controller with a method `def inbox.`

If the user is a group member then inbox returns a JSON object.

If the user is not a member, then inbox should redirect thanks to CanCan permissions.

How do I write an rspec to test these two use cases?

Current spec:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe GroupsController do
  include Devise::TestHelpers

  before (:each) do
    @user1 = Factory.create(:user)
    @user1.confirm!
    sign_in @user1
    @group = Factory(:group)
    @permission_user_1 = Factory.create(:permission, :user => @user1, :creator_id => @user1.id, :group => @group)
  end

  describe "GET inbox" do
    it "should be successful" do
      get inbox_group_path(@group.id), :format => :json
      response.should be_success
    end
  end
end
```

Routes:

```
inbox_group GET /groups/:id/inbox(.:format) {:controller=>"groups", :action=>"inbox"}
```

Routes File:

```
resources :groups do
  member do
    get 'vcard', 'inbox'
  end
  ....
end
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

This is how I do this:

```
describe "GET index" do
  it "returns correct JSON" do
    # @groups.should have(2).items
    get :index, :format => :json
    response.should be_success
    body = JSON.parse(response.body)
    body.should include('group')
    groups = body['group']
    groups.should have(2).items
    groups.all? {|group| group.key?('customers_count')}.should be_true
    groups.any? {|group| group.key?('customer_ids')}.should be_false
  end
end
```

I'm not using cancan, therefore I cannot help with this part.

Comment: Thanks Tried that but I get an error: "Failure/Error: get :inbox, :format => :json
     ActionController::RoutingError:
       No route matches {:controller=>"groups", :format=>:json, :action=>"inbox"}
     # ./controllers/groups_controller_spec.rb:19
" Which is strange considering rake routes yields: inbox_group GET    /groups/:id/inbox(.:format)                                                                       {:controller=>"groups", :action=>"inbox"}

Comment: try to provide the path to get with url_for - http://apidock.com/rails/ActionDispatch/Integration/RequestHelpers/get

Comment: Strange. Sorry, not sure what I'm doing wrong. "Failures:

  1) GroupsController GET index should be successful
     Failure/Error: get inbox_group_path(@group.id), :format => :json
     ActionController::RoutingError:
       No route matches {:controller=>"groups", :format=>:json, :action=>"/groups/33/inbox"}
     # ./controllers/groups_controller_spec.rb:16
"

Comment: Hmm.. it looks more like a Rails' bug now :)

Comment: The controller method ends with:     render :json => {:convlist => @convList }    
Could that be the issue?

Comment: I guess that it's a bug somewhere between rspec and Rails' ActionDispatch::Integration::RequestHelpers. It does figure out the controller somehow (rspec?)

Comment: I think it's CanCan, if I comment out load_and_authorize_resource in the controller it works

Comment: Does rspec need the csrt value? On dev, when my browser hits the controller I see the following in the logs: "Parameters: {"id"=>"173", "_"=>"1305334260963"}" but in rspec in the test logs I only see: Parameters: {"id"=>126}

Comment: Afaik - no. And the underscore is probably jquery cache busting.

Comment: Please keep me posted if you find out how to work-around the cancan issue. I'm curious.

Comment: I have the same routing error problem, anyone found a solution?

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes it might be good enough to verify if `response` contains valid JSON and to show actual response otherwise, here is an example:

```
it 'responds with JSON' do
  expect {
    JSON.parse(response.body)
  }.to_not raise_error, response.body
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
_expected = {:order => order.details}.to_json
response.body.should == _expected
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the first thing you want to do is to check that the response is of the correct type, i.e. that it has the `Content-Type` header set to `application/json`, something along the lines of:

```
it 'returns JSON' do
  expect(response.content_type).to eq(Mime::JSON)
end
```

Then, depending on your case, you might want to check whether the response can be parsed as JSON, like [wik](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20246051/505650) suggested:

```
it 'responds with JSON' do
  expect {
    JSON.parse(response.body)
  }.to_not raise_error
end
```

And you could merge the above two into a single test if you feel like two tests for checking JSON response validity are too much.

Answer (score 0):

To assert JSON you can do this too:

```
ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(response.body).should == ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(
  {"error" => "&nbsp;An email address is required&nbsp;"}.to_json
)
```

[This](http://www.idolhands.com/ruby-on-rails/specs-and-testing/writing-specs-for-controller-actions-that-return-json) blog gives some more ideas.